# Create Local Testing Account for C# ASP.NET MVC5 Web Application Which Uses Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I'm picking up where someone left off on a C# ASP.NET MVC5 web application. The app uses Identity authentication, which I haven't worked with.

Is there an efficient way to create a local testing user for the application? Or can I simply disable the authentication and set a specific user role for local testing purposes? Ultimately all I want to do is add a few minor features to the existing app.

All search string permutations I've thrown at Google return nothing but information regarding how to add this type of authentication to an existing ASP.NET project.

Comment: OWIN allows you to use middleware for authentication in an ASP.NET MVC application. You have not specified what kind authentication middleware that you are using so it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I removed the reference to OWIN as it distracts from the crux of my issue. I just need to get past the authentication when I run the app locally. Thank you.